# Extent Reports C# NUnit3 Parallel Testing Selenium Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, selenium, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, nunit-3.0

So I am reporting Using ExtentReports on my NUnit3 Selenium Tests in VS 2015.

When my test are run in series I had no issue reporting each instance into my report. However once I ran my tests in parallel the report would simply write each test and every time a parallel test would complete it would overwrite my previous report called. I have been researching a while and cannot see where my logic is flawed, can someone please look at my code? I have the report set up in my base class and I am calling the instance of the report there under a One Time Setup Attribute.

internal class ExtentManager
        {

```
        private static readonly ExtentReports _instance =
            new ExtentReports("(_NameofMyReport_)", DisplayOrder.NewestFirst);


        static ExtentManager()
        {
        }

        private ExtentManager()
        {
        }

        public static ExtentReports Instance
        {
            get { return _instance; }
        }
    }


        protected ExtentReports extent;
        protected ExtentTest test;


   [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void FixtureInit()
        {
            extent = ExtentManager.Instance;
            extent = new ExtentReports(FPATH(),false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had a similar issue recently. i think its due to a lot of write requests happening to the file at the same time, i got around this by creating a singleton class that can create the report and write the logs to it for each test.